# How do I set text color when using PreferenceFragmentCompat?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

I am overriding the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` class from the v7 support library to provide a settings screen in my application. I need to set the text color of the items in the `PreferenceScreen`.

This is what I have tried (in `styles.xml`) -

```
<style name="AppTheme.Preference" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppTheme.Preference</item>
</style>
```

But this doesn't change the color. How do I go about setting the preference screen text color ?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by using `android:textColorPrimary` instead of `android:textColor`.